# Proof $\left| n x^{n-1}\right| =\frac{H n \left| x\right| ^{n-1}}{H}\leq \frac{(\left| x\right| +H)^n}{H}$

Tags: calculus

I was given this in the textbook, it does not say anything els apart from the fact that H>0.

$$\left| n x^{n-1}\right| =\frac{H n \left| x\right| ^{n-1}}{H}\leq \frac{(\left| x\right| +H)^n}{H}$$.

Now how would one go about proving that this inequality is true. Could one use induction?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simpler way
is using Bernoulli's inequality
(BI):
$(1+x)^n
\ge 1+nx
$
for positive integer $n$
and real $x \ge 0$.

This is easily proved by induction,
which is why it
is more elementary than
the binomial theorem.

From BI,
if $x \ge 0$,
$(x+H)^n
=x^n(1+H/x)^n
\ge x^n(1+nH/x)
= x^n + nHx^{n-1}
$.

Therefore
(I think the $x^n$ term
is missing from what you wrote),
$\dfrac{(x+H)^n-x^n}{H}
\ge \dfrac{(x^n + nHx^{n-1})-x^n}{H}
= \dfrac{ nHx^{n-1}}{H}
=  nx^{n-1}
$.

Answer (score 0):

The term on the left is the second term of the binomial expansion of the term on the right. Since the expansion is a sum of positive numbers, the sum will be at least as large as each individual term.

I am ignoring the $\lvert n x^{n-1}\rvert$ term on the left, because it has little to do with the rest.